# Can Amazon WAF be used to protect Beanstalk applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking at hardening our security systems and want to introduce a firewall and the features that Amazon's WAF has to offer.

It appears however, WAF is only designed for use with CloudFront distributions.

Can it also be used for Beanstalk environments so it can sit in front of the load balancer preventing any rogue traffic getting through to the application layer?

UPDATE:  To anyone coming across this question,  WAF is now available to ALBs(Application Load Balancer), see https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/AWS-WAF-now-available-on-Application-Load-Balancer/ for further information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WAF only supports CloudFront at this time. Amazon has received lots of customer feedback and requests for adding ELB support to WAF, and I believe they are working on that feature, but it isn't available at this time. So if you want to use WAF with Elastic Beanstalk right now you would have to place a CloudFront distribution in front of your Beanstalk application.

**UPDATE:** Amazon's WAF firewall is [now available to load balancers](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/).

Comment: Thanks Mark for the clarification.

Comment: UPDATE: Amazons WAF firewall is now available to load balancers.   https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/AWS-WAF-now-available-on-Application-Load-Balancer

Answer (score -1):

Just for completeness, here's the link to how you can [associate to an existing ELB to WAF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-working-with.html#web-acl-associating-cloudfront-distribution).

Currently, it is only available to the following regions:

- US East (N. Virginia)
- US West (Oregon)
- EU (Ireland)
- Asia Pacific (Tokyo)

[image]

Comment: The document you linked doesn't mention Elastic Beanstalk.